# Boolean disjunction (OR) using mocha and chai

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, karma-runner, chai

I have the following scenario in which I have to check that an URL was build correctly provided some query arguments. I do not expect the system to apply an specific order in the rendered URL, so I came with the following test case which I expected to work:

```
it('test that url is built correctly', function () {
    var args = {
        arg1: 'value1',
        arg1: 'value2'
    };

    var rendered_url = render_url(args);

    expect(rendered_url).to.equal('/my/url?arg1=value1&arg2=value2')
                     .or.to.equal('/my/url?arg2=value2&arg1=value1')
    ;
});
```

I was pretty surprised to the `or` chain to not exists as it makes the statement construction process tidy and cozy.

I know I can workaround this in many ways (for example, using `satisfy`), but I wonder:

- Whether I cannot find the pattern to achieve in a similar way what I want in the documentation(I have read it thoroughly)...
- ... or whether there exists a good reason to not include this construction in chai...
- ... or whether there exists an alternative way to achieve a construction similar to the one in the example (tweaking, other frameworks, etc)

Answer (score 7):

You could use `to.include` or `.match`:

```
var chai = require("chai");
var expect = chai.expect;

var option1 = '/my/url?arg1=value1&arg2=value2';
var option2 = '/my/url?arg2=value2&arg1=value1';

var possible = [option1, option2];

var re = /^\/my\/url\?arg1=value1&arg2=value2|\/my\/url\?arg2=value2&arg1=value1$/;

it('1', function () {
    var rendered_url = option1;
    expect(possible).to.include(rendered_url);
    expect(rendered_url).to.match(re);
});

it('2', function () {
    var rendered_url = option2;
    expect(possible).to.include(rendered_url);
    expect(rendered_url).to.match(re);
});

it('3', function () {
    var rendered_url = "foo";
    expect(possible).to.include(rendered_url);
});

it('4', function () {
    var rendered_url = "foo";
    expect(rendered_url).to.match(re);
});
```

The first 2 tests will pass, the last 2 will fail.

I've not done it in this example but both `possible` and `re` could be generated by a function rather than hand-coding all possible permutations of arguments.

I suspect the reason that `.or` is not in Chai is that it would complicate Chai's code quite a bit and make it more cumbersome to use for regular cases. Right now when `.equal` is called, *it knows it is terminal*. If Chai allowed to use `.or`, then `.equal` could not know right away whether it is terminal or not. Even if you had something like `expect(foo).to.equal(bar)`, the call to `equal` cannot know that it is terminal. You'd have to do something like what some promises library do to signal that the code is finished with a promise and have a call saying "I'm done here" so it would look like `expect(foo).to.equal(bar).end()`. I'm not saying it would be *impossible* but it would have wide-ranging repercussions.

Comment: Maybe I should have noted that I was more interested in the way to achieve a easy-to-read and clear phrase construction for disjunction instead that a way to solve the URL specific problem(that was just an example), reason why I do not like very much using RE. Not enough easy to read for a test case in my opinion, I try to avoid them whenever I can, specifically for such easy kind of tests.

However, to use ``include`` is a relatively good way(not the best) to achieve what I was looking for, at least for tests cases in which disjuntive clauses must ``equal`` something.

Comment: The question asked has deeper philosophy then just asserting possible values of a property. What about checking undefined or empty in Chai syntax `expect(object).to.be.undefined.or.be.empty`?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
expect(rendrered_url).to.satisfy(function(url){
    return url === '/my/url?arg1=value1&arg2=value2 || url === '/my/url?arg2=value2&arg1=value1';
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I also discovered that `satisfy` can be used for this purpose, however I think this way breaks the whole reading philosophy of semantic chains.

Comment: Agreed, it would be nice if you could use or.